# Free Web Manager for Asp .Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, file-manager

I'm looking for free Asp .Net Application that acts like Web Manager enabling users to upload and download file? Download alone should do it. Do you know of any application of that kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these...

[Web File Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/WebFileManager.aspx) @ CodeProject

[QtFile](http://qtfile.codeplex.com/) @ CodePlex

[MorphFolia](http://morphfolia.codeplex.com/) - More of a framework, if you don't mind using those

[Silverlight Server File Manager](http://slfilemanager.codeplex.com/) - If you don't mind using Silverlight.

Comment: In addition to this list, I recommend you to take a look at [FileVista](http://www.gleamtech.com/products/filevista/web-file-manager), it's free for one-user.